# Does NOLOCK on Views propagate to the underlying tables?

Tags: sql-server, locking

If you include a `NOLOCK` hint on a `select from a VIEW`, does that `NOLOCK` hint propagate down into the tables joined within the view?  If not, what's the purpose of locking a view?

Sample view code:

```
CREATE VIEW [my_custom_view]
AS
  SELECT
    a1.[column_a], a1.[column_b], a1.[column_c], a1.[column_d]
  FROM
    [table_a] a1
    JOIN [table_b] b1 ON b1.[column_a] = a1.[column_b]
```

And the NOLOCK statement:

```
SELECT 
  [column_a], [column_b]
FROM
  [my_custom_view] NOLOCK
```

Comment: I'm assuming sql server 2000, because 2005 and later don't support that syntax for the locking hint.

Comment: @Joel SQL 2005 does support this